# How to get Object values which have multiple rows in it

Tags: c#, json, excel

I am converting a `JSON` string into a object and this object contains multiple records of a table like a row structure. each row contains some set values. It's like an object within an object. I am trying to read the value of these objects but I am unsuccessful.

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

//converting json data into array
JavaScriptSerializer ss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object itm = ss.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
```

In this response stream object gives the json string with multiple values and I am converting this into object using javascriptserializer. At debugging mode I have seen that all the data is there in this object in multiple rows where each rows in itself is also a object .

These rows store information like offer_id, name as  keys and  there values. I want to write a loop to call this keys and its value to perform further action. But I am unable to call these data in the loop.

Comment: have you tried just putting the result into a single cell instead of a range?

Comment: actually previously i was creating the object with just values with no key name for those values and it was working fine but now i my object has data in mulitple row and each row has multiple keys with there value and now this code is failing. i just want to know how to put my object itm in loop so that i can get the stored value in it

Comment: I am seriously looking for solution ASAP

Comment: do you not know the `Type` of the object which you are deserialising?
When I have used `JavaScriptSerializer` in the past I have just deserialised to the object that I serialised in the first place...
`MyClass myClassObject = ss.Deserialize<MyClass>(responseFromServer);`

Comment: i have now deserialized it and getting all the data in myclassobject in a array format. now each row has multiple object like offer_id->2
person ->"abcd". there can be so info like that. so i want to calculate the total number of it and it also doesnt show data like key ->key name and value -> value name. to print all this data in excel i have to write all this key one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way I would use a JavaScriptSerializer would be to

```
//Serialise
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string str = js.Serialize(new Thing() { ID = "111" });

//Deserialise
Thing thing = js.Deserialize<Thing>(str);
```

however if you do not know the Type to convert back to you can

```
Dictionary<string, object> dic = (Dictionary<string, object>)js.DeserializeObject(str);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValue in dic)
{
    keyValue.Key; <-- this is the property name (ID)
    keyValue.Value; <-- this is the property value ("111")
}
```

and then just handle the key value pairs you receive.

Comment: the error should tell you why it failed... and highlight the types to declare your dictionary as...

can you show the error?